# How do i optimize line detection for different images?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, edge-detection, hough-transform

A little context :  
 I am trying to detect vanishing points of  a cube and then group together lines having same vanishing points 
I encounter problem during the edge/line detection phase.

---

For e.g :

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjp0w.jpg)

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSOqR.png)

---

1. The thing is I get the desired output for hough line with minor modifications on the parameters [thresholding,canny,Hough_Line] .
2. So for eg, I optimized the parameter for this particular image  [Input1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGKDT.jpg) , I get the desired output.
3. But if i apply the same values to  [Different Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKH7d.jpg) then there a lot of duplicate lines detected for the same line.
4. I already have written a filtering algorithm to join similar lines. But the lines detected here have very different [rho,theta] and i have to increase the threshold value of the filtering algorithm by a lot which ends up impacting other lines.
5. I think the problem is because of the line breaking up during the edge detection and hence interpreted as different line , i am not sure.
6. I've tried using dilation and erosion in preprocessing but I encounter the same problem i.e different kernel size for different images , so i commented that part out.
7. I am fine with having to adjust the parameters for different images but the difference here is very large and so i feel like the problem here is in my preprocessing function.
8. I've pasted the functions that I thought were relevant to this question to avoid cluttering , if anybody requires the whole i can share the github link.

---

Code:

```
def pre_processing(path):

'''
    pre_processing:

            Param  : 
                path : Path for the image to processed.

            Return :
                edge_image : NumpyArray that stores the grayscale values of 
                             Input image.
'''

image = cv2.imread(path)

image = cv2.bitwise_not(image)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# print("Gray:",gray,"\n")
# plt.imshow(gray,cmap='gray')
# plt.show()

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)

# print("blur:",blur,"\n")
# plt.imshow(blur,cmap='gray')
# plt.show()

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,50,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)



return thresh
```

---

```
def filter_threshold(indexes,filter_indexes,filt_rho = 20,filt_theta= 0.2):

'''
    Filter_threshold:

        Param:
            indexes :  The raw [rho,theta] values with duplicates for same line.
            filter_indexes : A list to store indexes of unique lines.
            filt_rho : acceptable rho ranges to group lines.
            filt_theta  : acceptable theta ranges to group lines.

        Return :  
            filter_indexes : Dataset that stores filtered(duplicate values) 
                             (rho,theta) values.
'''
a = 0

rho = indexes[a][0]
theta = indexes[a][1]
unfilt_indexes = []

for j in range(len(indexes)):

    
    if rho<0:
        rho *= -1
        theta -= np.pi

    curr_rho = indexes[j][0]
    curr_theta = indexes[j][1]

    if curr_rho<0:
        curr_rho *= -1
        curr_theta -= np.pi

    if a == j:
        pass
    elif (0 <= abs(curr_rho-rho) <filt_rho) and (0 <= abs(curr_theta-theta)<filt_theta):

        pass

    else:
        unfilt_indexes.append([curr_rho,curr_theta])

filter_indexes.append([rho,theta])

if len(unfilt_indexes)>0:
    x = filter_threshold(unfilt_indexes,filter_indexes)

return filter_indexes
```

---

```
path = "/work/cubes/4.jpg"
thresh = pre_processing(path)

edge_image = cv2.Canny(thresh,100,200)

hough_threshold = 40
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edge_image,1,(np.pi/180),hough_threshold)

filtered_indexes = []
filtered_indexes = filter_threshold(lines,filtered_indexes,20,0.2)
```

Comment: what's exactly the problem? Thresholding paraneters? Canny parameters? Hough parameters? I suggest to use LSD or EDLines instead of threshold/canny.

Comment: @Micka I think the problem arises somewhere between preprocessing and canny. I am not able to properly frame the question , but the problem I have is the duplicate lines detected during hough transform for this [image](https://imgur.com/gallery/llQeEpd)  can be  removed by using my filtering algorithm but not for this [image](https://imgur.com/a/xQxD36u). Initially i thought it was due to filtering algorithm but the lines have large differences. So i am guessing it is due to fault in canny or preprocessing.I am looking into the algorithms you mentioned. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little sad, when you have such clean images where the line segments are so easy to follow, to use sledgehammers like Hough or LSD and try to retrieve a solution from the mess so obtained.

Also note that the vanishing points can be obtained from the hexagonal outline alone.

Below, the hexagon obtained by simple outline detection (on  Different Image). From the outline, you can segment out the sides by looking for long stretches of aligned pixels. (Douglas-Peucker is an option.)

[image]

More generally, you can segment out all white regions and fit polygons to them to get pieces of the edges and extend them to the vanishing points.